# Is it possible to have two templates classes with the same name but different template types in .NET?

Tags: .net, templates

Is it possible to have the following two classes in the same namespace? Because compiler throws an error to me:

```
public abstract class EPiPresenter<TView, TPageDataType> : Presenter<TView> 
    where TView : class, IView 
    where TPageDataType : PageData
{
}

public abstract class EPiPresenter<TView, TDataType> : Presenter<TView>
    where TView : class, IView
    where TDataType : CatalogContentBase
{

}
```

PageData and CatalogContentBase do not have any inheritance relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. To quote MSDN:

> The fully qualified name of a class is constructed by concatenating
>   the names of all the namespaces that contain the type

Edit: Thanks to usr for noticing. MSDN is not entirely accurate. The number of type arguments gets included as well.

`class GenericType1<TType1>`  gets translated to

> GenericType1`1

and `class GenericType2<TType1, TType2>` gets translated to

> GenericType2`2

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible because only the *number* of type arguments counts. The CLR type name (as returned by `Type.FullName`) actually looks something like

```
Namespace.TypeName`2
```

where the `2` is the number of type arguments (and the accent character is not a typo).